# How to set time to live(TTL) in Redis OM

Tags: redis, ttl, redisjson

I am using Redis OM in my spring boot application, I have set Redis configuration and TTL in application.properties, every configuration is ok but TTL is not working.I have added below dependency to use Redis OM

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.redis.om</groupId>
        <artifactId>redis-om-spring</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
```

I have added this configuration in application.properties :

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.cache.cache-names=Redis_EMR`
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=900000
```

moreover i have started Redis OM by this docker command :

**docker run -d -p 6379:6379 redislabs/redismod**

I want to delete redis cache every 15 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Redis OM is designed to work with Redis Stack.  Try using this:

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 redis/redis-stack
```

This will make sure you have the expected versions of RediSearch and RedisJSON .